# interpreting coin base api historical price data

Tags: api, coinbase.com

i'm looking at the coin based api and they provide historical price data

https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/historical?page=1

which returns results like this

```
2014-02-22T04:47:06-05:00,575.39
2014-02-22T04:36:57-05:00,575.36
2014-02-22T04:27:28-05:00,577.26
2014-02-22T04:19:01-05:00,576.73
2014-02-22T04:10:21-05:00,576.96
2014-02-22T03:57:22-05:00,579.31
2014-02-22T03:48:48-05:00,574.41
2014-02-22T03:40:22-05:00,572.71
2014-02-22T03:27:03-05:00,577.84
2014-02-22T03:18:43-05:00,574.86
2014-02-22T03:11:01-05:00,571.28
2014-02-22T02:57:25-05:00,568.91
2014-02-22T02:47:18-05:00,567.27
2014-02-22T02:27:11-05:00,568.28
2014-02-22T02:17:59-05:00,564.0
```

I can see the date time and price but for example in the first line
 2014-02-22
 T04:47:06-05:00,
 575.39

what format is the time in it shows hh:mm:ss-??:??,

Answer (score 1):

This seems to correspond to the [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) datetime format, specifically the *complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds with time zone designation* format.

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (e.g. 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
```

The `TZD` hereby stands for *time zone designator*, which is a `±hh:mm` offset from UTC* .

Accordingly, "-05:00" would represent [Eastern Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/est.html).

<sup>* UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) is also known as GMT (Greenwich Mean Time), i.e. the time in London's time zone.</sup>